# renderWith output visible in console, but does not update browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, silverstripe

I'm unable to get my controller to properly render the results of an AJAX request in my browser. I receive the correct html response using the specified Include for Ajax requests, but it is only visible in my browser's console. The page itself does not render the new content. What am I missing?

Here is my simplified controller for searching products:

```
class ProductSearch_Controller extends Page_Controller {
  public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {

    // external api request, parsing response, returning as ArrayList $units

    $return_data = array(
      'Products' => $units
    );

    if($request->isAjax()) {
      return $this->customise($return_data)->renderWith('SearchResults');
    } else {
      return $return_data;
    }
  }
}
```

The index method actually pulls in json data from an external source, parses it, and then passes it into an ArrayList, `$units`, which is then made available to the template as `Products`. Here is the simplified ProductSearch.ss template:

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="productsearch__container">
      <aside>$SearchForm</aside>
      <main>
        <h2>Search Results</h2>
        <% include SearchResults %>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here's the SearchResults template Include:

```
<div class="product__container">
    <% loop $Products %>
      <a href="$URL" class="product">
        <h3>Unit $UnitNo</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Price: $Lot_Price</li>
          <li>SQFT: $SQFT</li>
          <li>Bedrooms: $bedrooms_no</li>
          <li>Baths: $baths_no</li>
        </ul>
      </a>
    <% end_loop %>
</div>
```

And here is my simplified javascript:

```
$("[name='example-filter-variable']").on('change', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var params = $( "#Form_SearchForm" ).serialize();
  $.get("url/example?" + params, function(data) {
    console.log("Data: " + data);
  });
});
```

Triggering the ajax event returns the appropriate response using the SearchResults.ss Include, which is visible in my console.log() output:

```
<div class="product__container">
      <a href="/homes/search/show/6/101" class="product">
        <h3>Unit 101</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Price: </li>
          <li>SQFT: 1531</li>
          <li>Bedrooms: 2</li>
          <li>Baths: 2</li>
        </ul>
      </a>

      <a href="/homes/search/show/12/102" class="product">
        <h3>Unit 102</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Price: </li>
          <li>SQFT: 1535</li>
          <li>Bedrooms: 2</li>
          <li>Baths: 2</li>
        </ul>
      </a>

    ... and so on

</div>
```

The problem is the template is actually being rendered in the browser. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in the template: `<% include SearchResults %>` is causing your template to include the SearchResults template.

You also don't have anything in your javascript to append your data into the DOM.

Try this template:

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="productsearch__container">
      <aside>$SearchForm</aside>
      <main>
        <h2>Search Results</h2>
        <div class="results"></div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

With this js:

```
$("[name='example-filter-variable']").on('change', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var params = $( "#Form_SearchForm" ).serialize();
  $.get("url/example?" + params, function(data) {
    console.log("Data: " + data);
    $(".results").append(data); // add something along these lines
  });
});
```

Comment: Of course! The issue was less to do with my templating, and more to do with the fact I simply forgot to _append the response_ into the DOM. Thank you!